# Can I edit a post without bumping it to the front page?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, editing, bumping

I often come across questions that are old and worked for the OP, but could be made better (formatting, spelling, etc.).  These reasons don't really warrant it going back up to the front page -- is there a to mark the edit as 'minor'?  Should there be?

(If there should be, I'm willing to raise the question on Meta.SE where such a feature request would belong.)

Comment: Ongoing feature request at main meta site: [Allow non-bumping minor edits, but review them on /review](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/122567)

Comment: The entire reason for bumping is to make sure all edits get reviewed not by a self-selecting group but by anyone reading the site. I very much doubt the Powers will ever change this. (Even mods can't do silent edits.)

Comment: @JosephWright That makes good sense, actually – I never thought about that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is an idea that comes up fairly frequently, on all different sites, with the best of intentions. In addition to the link Paul gave, there's [Is it possible for me to edit my answer without bumping the question up the list?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/258435), [Is there a way to edit a question without bumping it to the front page?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/23241), [Could we have the ability to mark a change as minor in questions or answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26483/could-we-have-the-ability-to-mark-a-change-as-minor-in-questions-or-answers) and [CHAOS-like option for moderators to edit without bumping](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/131508) (which [cites long-time dev balpha](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/89?m=934917#934917)), to name just a few.

Unfortunately, there's a high potential for abuse, as Joseph alluded to. And in the more pleasant and common case of not-abuse, bumps give good older posts a chance to earn a few more upvotes and spread a little more knowledge to the browsing set.